# proftpd join multiple paths into single virtual filesystem for specified user

Tags: ftp, directory, user-accounts, proftpd, vfs

I've tryed configure proftpd for specified user, that join at least two directory paths as single filesystem tree, including chroot option (rootdir). Is it possible any way? Proftpd has support for that scenario?

I don't want do any mounts -bind on system side, because in the future that config will grow into very complicated submount mess.

I've tryed some experiments with rewrite, but without any effect.

Years ago I saw that possibility with custom ftp server built to OS/2 system, but at this time this is completly useless.

Comment: What about softlinks?

Comment: softlinks are not working properly when ftp user is used with chroot. I didn't found any software for Linux. OS/2 is not maintained for a years.